# Columns vertical lines disappeared

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have removed few columns from excel file and saved it. When I open it again columns(A, B, C) lines has been removed automatically. I happened with me every time I removed the columns of file

How can get vertical lines back ?

[image]

Comment: I think you mean you have hidden the columns (A,B and C). Just click on the D column (at the top so the whole column highlights) then drag left toward where A should be. Right click on the highlighted column and select "unhide".

Comment: Can you add an image?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - Please check the image.

Comment: @JustinDoward - Please check my updated question.

Comment: Check if the cells'  right border l been formatted with white color. Select a column and set the border to "No border". What's the result?

Comment: It looks like the text is just overlapping into the adjacent cells? if so you can either resize the A column or turn on wordwrap to prevent running into the next cells if it is a problem.

Comment: @JustinDoward - Columns name A B C.. looks not dependent on data. When I resize A, nothing happens to data. Only A B C.. going left right.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - After selecting column, right click-->Format cells-->Border, applying it nothing doing.

Comment: Try to create a new worksheet on the same file and a new workbook, then delete some columns. Save them and re-open as you did before. Do both the newly created worksheet and workbook also have the same problem?

Comment: All your data is in column A. You will need to split the data into the correct columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner - How can I do that?